# Power Function in Raspberry PI

Tags: c, function, raspberry-pi, pow

I'm having problem with pow() in Raspberry PI. I used it and simply turn gpio pin like this:

```
*((unsigned int *)(GPIO_PIN_ON)) = ( 1 * pow(2,16) ); // 1 << 16
```

GPIO_PIN_ON is my constant i define at top. This works fine. I don't even have to include "Math.h" but when I make "GPIOsetFunction()" in other file and use pow() even with "math.h" library it gives me this error:

```
gpio.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
gpio.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
>> gpio.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `pow'
gpio.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
gpio.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
```

Here it indicate that pow() is undefine. Can someone help me please.

P.S: I'm converting BakingPI tutorials from Assembly to C and I don't want to use Shift operator.

Below is the code I run successfully without "math.h" and without "-lm" and if "-lm" is the solution and how I'm able to run this? (This is a complete code of OK-02 of BAKING-PI tutorial)

P.S2: I'm using YAGARTO Compiler.

```
#include <sys/types.h>

void main(void);

#define GPIO_BASE 538968064 //0x20200000
#define GPIO_PIN_FUNC (GPIO_BASE+4)
#define GPIO_PIN_ON (GPIO_BASE+28)
#define GPIO_PIN_OFF (GPIO_BASE+40)

void main(void) {
register int counter = 0;
*((unsigned int *)(GPIO_PIN_FUNC)) = ( 1 * pow(2,18) ); //1 << 18
while (1 == 1) {    // forever
    *((unsigned int *)(GPIO_PIN_OFF)) = ( 1 * pow(2,16) ); //1 << 16
    counter = 4128768; //0x3f0000;
    while (counter--);
    *((unsigned int *)(GPIO_PIN_ON)) = ( 1 * pow(2,16) ); // 1 << 16
    counter =  4128768; //0x3f0000;
    while (counter--);
}
// should never get here
}
```

Comment: Are you linking the program directly using `ld` ? Use `gcc` to link, in addition to the answer by ouah.

Comment: Why do you don't want to use bitwise shift?

Comment: That is a requirement to not use bitwise shift. I did with it successfully. I Add more stuff in question please see.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link with math library. Append `-lm` to your compilation (link) commmand line.